# surjectivity doubts homology of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have an homomorphism between two abelian groups: $\varphi: A \rightarrow H_n (D^n, S^{n-1};A) $ such that $a \mapsto [a \cdot f]$ where $[-]$ is the relative Homology class of $H_n (D^n, S^{n-1};A)$ and $f: \Delta^n \rightarrow S^{n-1}$ is an homeomorphism which restricts to the homeomorphism between the boundaries, i.e. $\partial \Delta^n \rightarrow S^{n-1}$.

I am having some trouble while proving that $\varphi$ is surjective. I have chosen an element $[c] \in H_n (D^n, S^{n-1};A)$ such that for some $a \in A$ we get $\varphi(a)=[a \cdot f]=[c]$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a \cdot f \sim c \Leftrightarrow (af -c) \in im\partial_{n+1} \subseteq ker\partial_n$ $\Rightarrow (af-c) \in ker\partial_n$ $\partial_n (af)=\partial_n(c)$ here I got stuck. Could somebody help me giving me some hints?

Comment: If your problem is to identify $H_n (D^n, S^{n-1})$, then you should probably look at the long exact sequence
$$\cdots \to H_n (S^{n-1}) \to H_n (D^n) \to H_n (D^n, S^{n-1}) \xrightarrow{\delta} H_{n-1} (S^{n-1}) \to H_{n-1} (D^n) \to \cdots$$
Since $D^n$ is contractible, you get an isomorphism $H_n (D^n, S^{n-1}) \cong H_{n-1} (S^{n-1})$ given by the connecting homomorphism $\delta$.

Comment: Yes Alejo, you are right! But what you said is already done the thing is to give an explicit isomorphism

Comment: To make it explicit, you should look at the morphism $\delta$. You will get something like you mention in your post, though I think there's a typo: the relative cycle generating $H_n (D^n, S^{n-1})$ should be represented by some $f\colon \Delta^n \to D^n$.

Comment: "so the long exact sequence reduces to a short exact sequence" well, yes, to a *very* short exact sequence $0 \to H_n (D^n, S^{n-1}) \xrightarrow{\delta} H_{n-1} (S^{n-1}) \to 0$